# get localstorage value from Blazor Web App .NET 8 in App.razor?

Tags: blazor

i want o change css file upon value in localstorage like this

```
@if(rtl)
{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/css/rtl/core.css" class="template-customizer-core-css" />
}
else
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/css/core.css" class="template-customizer-core-css" />
}
```

so i need to get rtl bool value from localstorage
thanks in advance

i injected jsruntime and used it in

```
bool rtl;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
 rtl= await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("localStorage.getItem", "rtl");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you can execute JS in OnInitializedAsync(), try like bellow

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        
    }

    rtl = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("localStorage.getItem", "rtl");
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but it is not executed , microsoft said : Making a root component interactive, such as the App component, isn't supported. Therefore, prerendering can't be disabled directly by the App component. so js cannot run in App.razor

Comment: ahh i didnt realise was in app razor, why do you need to change between css files?